# Java 8 stream - merge collections of objects sharing the same Name and who follow each other

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Suppose a class Person:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int amount;
}
```

and suppose a collection of Person:

```
persons = [{"Joe", 5}, {"Joe", 8}, {"Joe", 10}, {"Jack", 3}, {"Jack",6}, {"Joe" 4}, 
           {"Joe", 7}, {"Jack", 12}, {"Jack", 15}, {"Luke", 10}, {"Luke", 12}]
```

What i want is to get list of Person with merged element who have same name and who follow each other and sum the amount (with  java 8 Stream); a list like this:

```
Perons = [{"Joe", 23}, {"Jack", 9}, {"Joe", 11}, {"Jack", 27}, {"Luke", 22}]
```

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 5):

You should create your own custom [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) for this.

```
class AdjacentNames {

    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Person last = null;

    void accumulate(Person person) {
        if (last != null && last.getName().equals(person.getName())) {
            last.setAmount(last.getAmount() + person.getAmount())
        } else {
            last = new Person(person.getName(), person.getAmount());  // Clone
            result.add(last);
        }
    }

    AdjacentNames merge(AdjacentNames other) {
        List<Person> other_list = other.finisher();

        if (other_list.size() > 0) {
            accumulate(other_list.remove(0));
            result.addAll(other_list);
            last = result.get(result.size()-1);
        }

        return this;
    }

    List<Person> finisher() {
        return result;
    }

    public static Collector<Person, AdjacentNames, List<Person>> collector() {
        return Collector.of(AdjacentNames::new,
                            AdjacentNames::accumulate,
                            AdjacentNames::merge,
                            AdjacentNames::finisher);
    }
}
```

And use like:

```
List<Person> result = persons.stream().collect(AdjacentNames.collector());
```

Comment: I always want people to be empowered to make their own custom `Collector`

Answer (score 4):

The solution you are looking for is bit complicated with stream approach, I would suggest to go with basic `for` loop and use `Map` with a duplicate logic for each sequence

```
List<Person> persons = List.of(new Person("Jeo", 5), new Person("Jeo", 5), new Person("Jack", 8),
            new Person("Luke", 5), new Person("Jeo", 5), new Person("Jeo", 5));

    List<Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Integer> check = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (Person per : persons) {

        if (check.containsKey(per.getName())) {
            check.compute(per.getName(), (k, v) -> v + per.getAmount());

        } else if (check.size() == 0) {
            check.put(per.getName(), per.getAmount());

        }else {
            result.add(check.entrySet().stream().map(e->new Person(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).findFirst().get());
            check.clear();
            check.put(per.getName(), per.getAmount());
        }
    }
    result.add(check.entrySet().stream().map(e->new Person(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).findFirst().get());
```

I would also suggest to go with `stream` approach to just get each `Person` sum based on name  by using [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [summingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and save them to `LinkedHashMap` by maintaining the order, and then convert each entry back to `Person` object.

```
person.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.summingInt(Person::getAmount)))
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(entry->new Person(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't answer the "*follow each other*" part of the question. (And there's a typo in `Collectore`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to group **all** person by name, and keep the ones that are together in the original list, I don't think a stream solution is a suitable solution, something with a for loop seems better and easier :

```
List<Person> output = new ArrayList<>();
Person toAdd = null;
for (Person current : persons) {
    if (toAdd == null) {
        toAdd = current;
    } else if (toAdd.getName().equals(current.getName())) {
        toAdd = new Person(toAdd.getName(), toAdd.getAmount() + current.getAmount());
    } else {
        output.add(toAdd);
        toAdd = current;
    }
}
output.add(toAdd);
```

Comment: got it with loop, i'm looking for stream. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

```
List<Person> result = persons.stream()
        .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (list, currentPerson) -> {
            // get the last person of the list being computed
            Person lastListPerson = list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(list.size() - 1);
            if (lastListPerson != null && currentPerson.name.equals(lastListPerson.name)) {
                // if the previous persone had the same name, just add the amount
                lastListPerson.amount += currentPerson.amount;
            } else {
                // if the previous person had a different name, clone the person and add it in the result list
                list.add(new Person(currentPerson));
            }
            return list;
        }, (a, b) -> a);
```

Comment: Note: This will mutate the first `Person` in every group of successive persons with the same name in the input data.  You probably should clone the person's data.